# How to create a windows Xp installer via Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-xp

I have a windows Application(C#) developed in Visual Studio 2015 on windows 10.

When i tried to install on windows XP and i get an error "The installer was interrupted before [Myapplication] could be installed.
You need to restart installer to try again"

I need help for creating the required setup file for Windows XP OS via VS 2015

Comment: xp only supports .net 4.0, maybe you use a newer .net version. Why do you still need XP support? XP is dead since 2014.